# Python - How to assign OpenMenu choice as a List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have created Frame with Entry widget to ask user to input his Username and select a team, that he want to join in and also I have created an OpenMenu Widget with 4 teams that user can join.

I want to know, how to assign list to OpenMenu variations as a list. For example: Selection "Team 1" = `team1Members` etc.

Also I want to know, how to assign data from Entry Widget to appropriate list. For example, if user have selected "Team 1", his username will append to `team1Members` list.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

team1Members = []
team2Members = []
team3Members = []
team4Members = []


class CollegeApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, selectionPage, TeamsPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.startMenu()

    def startMenu(self):
        heading = Label(self, text="College Tournament Points\n Count Software",
                        font=('Arial', 25))
        heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=240, pady=40)

        start_Btn = Button(self, text="Start", font="Arial 16", width=8,
                           command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(selectionPage))
        start_Btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=5)

        exit_Btn = Button(self, text="EXIT", font="Arial 16", width=8,
                          command=self.controller.destroy)
        exit_Btn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=5)

    def starting_Program(self):
        pass


class selectionPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.teamSelect()

    def teamSelect(self):
        heading = Label(self, text="Become a member of a Team",
                        font=('Arial', 25))
        heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=200, pady=40)

        teams = Button(self, text="Teams", font="Arial 24", width=15,
                       command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(TeamsPage))
        teams.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=270, pady=5)

class TeamsPage(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):
        headingTest = Label(self, text="Enter your Username:", font="Arial 20")
        headingTest.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=0)

        usernameEnter = Entry(self, width=40)
        usernameEnter.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=10)

        UserName = StringVar(self)
        UserName.set("Team1")

        AdditionalText = Label(self, text="Please select a team:", font="Arial 18") 
        AdditionalText.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=15)

        teamSelection = OptionMenu(self, UserName, "Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team 4") # How to link those variations to team list? For example: Team 1 = team1Members?
        teamSelection.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        confirmBtn = Button(self, text="Submit", font="Arial 16",
                            command=()) # Command to Save username in teamXMembers list. Depends on the user selection 
        confirmBtn.config(height=4, width=12)
        confirmBtn.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E, padx=65, pady=300)

        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = CollegeApp()
    app.geometry("800x500")
    app.title('Points Counter')
    app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of this window:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways that could achieve this. The First would be to create a list of teams and unpack them using `*` in optionMenu then use if else condition to check which list to append to.

Here is a demo

```
class TeamsPage(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.teamList = ["Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team 4"]

        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):
        ...
        self.usernameEnter = Entry(self, width=40)
        self.usernameEnter.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=10)

        self.userName = StringVar(self)
        self.userName.set("Team1")

        teamSelection = OptionMenu(self, self.userName, *self.teamList) 
        teamSelection.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        confirmBtn = Button(self, text="Submit", font="Arial 16",
                            command= self.updateTeamList) # Command to Save username in teamXMembers list. Depends on the user selection 
        ...

        
    def updateTeamList(self):
      
        if self.userName.get() == self.teamList[0]:
            team1Members.append(self.usernameEnter.get())

        elif self.userName.get() == self.teamList[1]:
            team2Members.append(self.usernameEnter.get())
         ...
```

but a better way would be to create a dictionary. something as shown

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.teamList = {"Team1": team1Members , "Team2": team2Members,
                         "Team3":team3Members, "Team 4": team4Members}

        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):

        ...
        self.usernameEnter = Entry(self, width=40)
        self.usernameEnter.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=10)

        self.userName = StringVar(self)
        self.userName.set("Team1")

        AdditionalText = Label(self, text="Please select a team:", font="Arial 18") 
        AdditionalText.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=15)

        teamSelection = OptionMenu(self, self.userName, *self.teamList.keys())
        teamSelection.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        confirmBtn = Button(self, text="Submit", font="Arial 16",
                            command= self.updateTeamList) # Command to Save username in teamXMembers list. Depends on the user selection 
        ...
    
    def updateTeamList(self):
       
        self.teamList[self.userName.get()].append(self.usernameEnter.get())
```

Comment: Thank you so much^^. This is exactly what I needed.